Need to combine two separate "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)"
I have two separate "Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)" that I'm trying to make work on one worksheet in Excel. I know you can't have two worksheet change events so I'm guessing I need to combine them somehow but I'm not sure how since they're completely unrelated to each other. Each code works individually but not together of course.
First Code - Adds today's date in Column A once a value is entered into Column B
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range
    
    For Each Cell In Target
    If Cell.Column = Range("B:B").Column Then
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value = Int(Now)
        Else
            Cells(Cell.Row, "A").Value = ""
        End If
    End If
    Next Cell

    End Sub

Second Code removes formula from cells in column H once a value is entered into column I
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cell As Range
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I1:I100000")) Is Nothing Then
        Set Cell = Me.Cells(Target.Row, "H")
        If Cell.HasFormula Then 
            Cell.Value = Cell.Value
        End If
    End If
    End Sub


I don't have enough reputation to comment on @FunThomas's answer, so posting this suggested edit to their code as an answer.
I modified to use Select Case instead of If/Elseif. I find Select Case easier to read and edit (e.g., if you want to trap change events for additional columns in future versions). Theoretically it is also more performant, but you'd only notice the difference with a very large dataset.
Here's @FunThomas's answer re-written using Select Case:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Change_Exit
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        Dim neighborCell As Range
        Set neighborCell = Cell.Offset(0, -1)
        
        Select Case Cell.Column
            Case 2 ' Column B
                If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                    neighborCell.Value = Date
                Else
                    neighborCell.Value = ""
                End If

            Case 9 ' Column I
                If neighborCell.HasFormula Then
                    neighborCell.Value = neighborCell.Value
                End If
        End Select        
    Next

Change_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub


Obviously, you cannot have 2 routines with the same name. Instead, you simply put the code into one routine. I guess the following should match your needs.
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    On Error GoTo Change_Exit
    
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Target
        Dim neighborCell As Range
        Set neighborCell = Cell.Offset(0, -1)
        
        If Cell.Column = 2 Then
            If Cell.Value <> "" Then
                neighborCell = Date
            Else
                neighborCell = ""
            End If
        ElseIf Cell.Column = 9 Then
            If neighborCell.HasFormula Then
                neighborCell.Value = neighborCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next

Change_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

I added a statement to disable the events while the the routine is running because writing a value into a cell via code would again trigger the event routine - you don't want that and in some circumstances (not here) this can lead to endless loops. You just need to ensure that the events are enabled again at the end of the routine.

I would use two sub-routines (named according to their job) and call them from the event:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

addTodaysDateToColumnA Target
makeValueStaticInColumnH Target

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Private Sub addTodaysDateToColumnA(rg As Range)
'First Code - Adds today's date in Column A once a value is entered into Column B
Dim c As Range
For Each c In rg
    If c.Column = 2 Then
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            c.Offset(, -1).Value = Int(Now)
        Else
            c.Offset(, -1).ClearContents
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Sub makeValueStaticInColumnH(rg As Range)
'Second Code removes formula from cells in column H once a value is entered into column I

Dim c As Range
For Each c In Intersect(rg, rg.Parent.Columns("I"))
    If c.Value <> "" And c.Offset(, -1).HasFormula Then
        With c.Offset(, -1)
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub

You can even put them in a public module (and make them public) to reuse the subs from other worksheets as well.
